# Validating XML in Perl with libxml and an XSD file

Tags: xml, perl, xsd, xml-validation, xml-libxml

I am trying to have my perl script get an Xxml file from online and validate it according to an XSD file.

The code to do this is as follows:

```
my $url = shift @ARGV;
my $response = $ua->get($url) || die "Can't fetch file";
my $file = $response->content;

my $schema_file = "schema.xsd";
my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $schema_file);
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc    = $parser->parse_string($file);
eval { $schema->validate($doc) };
die $@ if $@;
```

Running this results in a cryptic error: "Element cropdata content check failure" (cropdata is the first of my nonroot tags).

In my XSD file, the entry looks like:

```
<xs:element name="cropdata">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
```

Then a bunch of "`<xs:element..../`>"
and then:

```
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Going into the perl debugger shows that after letting the line `"my $doc    = $parser->parse_string($file);"` run, $doc prints as XML::LibXML::Document=SCALAR(0x6b99f0).

Can anyone help me shed light on what I am doing wrong? (Warning: it may be a dumb mistake, I wouldn't put it past myself).

Comment: Try `use Data::Dumper; Dumper($doc);` right after the parse_string call -- does the $doc object look correct?

Comment: @Ether, $doc will almost certainly be a scalar ref to a number that is the memory address of a C data structure.

Comment: What does the input XML look like?  Is it valid per the schema?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you Jim. Turns out that the sample xml file I had been provided was invalid, and lo and behold, upon checking and correcting it in xmllint, everything works.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer and accept it please (that way the question won't show as "unanswered", which means people waste time looking at it) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the sample xml file I had been provided was invalid, and lo and behold, upon checking and correcting it in xmllint, everything works.